# Replace Strings Dynamically using Typescript Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, string, typescript

I am trying to create an offer letter that will replace certain placeholders with the details of the candidate that is selected from a list. I was instructed not to use **jquery** or **JS** that means I cannot use *$* or *document.getelementbyId*. I am still a learner so I need help with writing thi code in pure typescript. Anyways, here are the details :-

I have created a dummy template list with clauses and each clause has a text associated with it

```
  templateList = [{

    templateId: 1,
    templateName: "Offer",
    clauses: [
      {
        clauseName: "Introduction",
        clauseId: 1,
        texts: [
          {
            text: "Hello <<Name>>, Welcome to the Machine",
            textId: 1,
          }]
      },
      {
        clauseName: "Address",
        clauseId: 2,
        texts: [
          {
            text: "<<Address>>",
            textId: 2,
          }]
      },
      {
        clauseName: "Date Of Joining",
        clauseId: 3,
        texts: [
          {
            text: "You can join us on <<DateOfJoining>>",
            textId: 3,
          }]
      },
    ]
  }]
```

there is also a list of candidates

```
  candidateList = [
    { name: "Simba", address: "Some Random Cave" },
    { name: "Doe John", address: "line 4, binary avenue, Mobo" },
    { name: "B Rabbit", address: "8 mile road, Detroit" },
    { name: "Peter Griffin", address: "Spooner Street" },
    { name: "Speedy Gonzales", address: "401, hole 34, Slyvester Cat Road" },
    { name: "Morty", address: "Time Machine XYZ" },
    { name: "Brock", address: "pokeball 420, Medic center" },
  ]
```

My task is to replace the string sandwiched between **<<>>** in the text of the template list (<<>> included), with the name or address of the candidate i have clicked on from the candidate list.

Here is the HTML :

```
<div style="display: block;">
    <button (click)="showTeplate()">Show template</button>
</div>
<hr /><br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <ul>
            <ol *ngFor="let x of candidateList">
                <a>{{x.name}}</a><br />
                <a><small>{{x.address}}</small></a>
                <hr />
            </ol>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
        <div class="templateDiv">
            <div *ngFor="let temp of clauseList">
                <span><strong class="textTemp">{{temp.clauseName}}</strong></span>
                <br/>
                <div *ngFor = "let x of temp.texts">
                    <p class="txt">{{x.text}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was also wondering if anyone could tell me if this can be an example of dynamic data points. Here is a https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ntu3lm

Please help me with this.

Comment: *"I was instructed not to use jquery or JS"*: but you tag the question with `javascript` and your first code block (`templateList = `) is JavaScript?

Comment: The tag shouldn't be there yes, but it helps to find people who can help and isn't that how we show an Array?

Comment: Your code isn't present in the stackblitz link.

Comment: Please check now @NicholasK

Comment: So you want to show the template when an entry is clicked? What is the purpose of the show template button then?

Comment: In the real world application, i'll have to choose from a list of templates and the texts in that particular template will be shown. The show template button is for that purpose. The candidate list will remain the same tho. I I select a candidate and its name is shown on the template along with the address, if required.

Comment: Hmm, lets focus on what you need to do *immediately* now. To simplify -- What do you expect to happen when I click on an entry?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, having internet issues.  Okay here is what should happen,  you click on show template, you get the selected template rendered on the screen, then you select a candidate, lets say Morty, from the candidate list. On selecting Morty, in the template <<Name>> should be replaced by morty and <<Address>> be replaced by Morty's address, it will be saved temporarily and sent to the user in the next step (thats not mentioned here).

Comment: also, if the user selects some other candidate Morty should be replaced by the other Name. Kinda like, dynamically changing names

Comment: @NicholasK any ideas, I've been trying but its all in vain rn

Answer (score 1):

**App component.ts**

```
candidateList = [
        { name: "Simba", address: "Some Random Cave", dateOfJoin: "5/4/2019" },
        { name: "Doe John", address: "line 4, binary avenue, Mobo" },
        { name: "B Rabbit", address: "8 mile road, Detroit" },
        { name: "Peter Griffin", address: "Spooner Street" },
        { name: "Speedy Gonzales", address: "401, hole 34, Slyvester Cat Road" },
        { name: "Morty", address: "Time Machine XYZ" },
        { name: "Brock", address: "pokeball 420, Medic center" }
      ];

      clauseList: Object[] = [];

      showTeplate(name: string, address: string, dateOfJoin: string) {
        this.clauseList = [];
        for (let template of this.templateList) {
          if (template.clauses != null) {
            for (let clause of template.clauses) {
              this.setClauseText(clause, address, name, dateOfJoin);
              this.clauseList.push(clause);
            }
          }
        }
        console.log("Clause list", this.clauseList);
      }

      setClauseText(clause: any, address, name, dateOfJoin) {
        let text = clause.texts[0].text;
        if (clause.clauseName === "Introduction") {
          const nameToReplace = this.getTextName(text);
          if (name !== undefined) {
            clause.texts[0].text = text.replace(nameToReplace, name.concat(","));
          } else clause.texts[0].text = text.replace(nameToReplace, "N/A");
        } else if (clause.clauseName === "Address") {
          if (address !== undefined)
            clause.texts[0].text = text.replace(text, address);
          else clause.texts[0].text = text.replace(text, "N/A");
        } else if (clause.clauseName === "Date Of Joining") {
          const dateOfJoinToReplace = this.getTextDateOfJoin(text);
          if (dateOfJoin !== undefined)
            clause.texts[0].text = text.replace(dateOfJoinToReplace, dateOfJoin);
          else clause.texts[0].text = text.replace(dateOfJoinToReplace, "N/A");
        }
        console.log("ClasueText ==", clause.texts[0].text);
      }

      getTextName(text: string) {
        const splitArray = text.split(" ");
        if (splitArray[2].includes(",")) 
          return splitArray[1] + " " + splitArray[2];
        else return splitArray[1];
      }

      getTextDateOfJoin(text: string) {
        const splitArray = text.split(" ");
        return splitArray[5];
      }
```

**App component.html**

```
<hr /><br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <ul>
            <ol *ngFor="let x of candidateList">
                <a (click)="showTeplate(x.name,x.address,x.dateOfJoin)">{{x.name}}</a><br />
                <a (click)="showTeplate(x.name,x.address,x.dateOfJoin)"><small>{{x.address}}</small></a>
                <hr />
            </ol>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
        <div class="templateDiv">
            <div *ngFor="let temp of clauseList">
                <span><strong class="textTemp">{{temp.clauseName}}</strong></span>
                <br/>
                <div *ngFor = "let x of temp.texts">
                    <p class="txt">{{x.text}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have modified your code, in particular way the showTemplate function.

Comment: Yup, it has the functionality that  I was looking for, thanks for that. BUT like I have mentioned that this is dummy data and the strings in the texts can vary. For example, take a look at this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ntu3lm I have added something in the introduction clause. Any ideas on how to tackle this situation?

Comment: also, I was trying to use the regex to solve this, as there can be 30-40 clauses in a template and not necessarily the same clauses.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the showTemplate function, now if you add something in the cluase it work, but it not possibile don't know what are the clauses name.

```
showTeplate(name: string, address: string, dateOfJoin: string) {
    this.clauseList = [];
    let tempList = new Array<any>();
    tempList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.templateList));
    for (let template of tempList) {
      if (template.clauses != null) {
        for (let clause of template.clauses) {
          this.setClauseText(clause, address, name, dateOfJoin);
          this.clauseList.push(clause);
        }
      }
    }
    console.log("Clause list", this.clauseList);
  }

  setClauseText(clause: any, address, name, dateOfJoin) {
    let text = clause.texts[0].text;
    if (clause.clauseName === "Introduction") {
      const nameToReplace = this.getText(text);
      if (name !== undefined) {
        clause.texts[0].text = text.replace(nameToReplace, name.concat(","));
      } else clause.texts[0].text = text.replace(nameToReplace, "N/A");
    } else if (clause.clauseName === "Address") {
       const addressToReplace = this.getText(text);
      if (address !== undefined)
        clause.texts[0].text = text.replace(addressToReplace, address);
      else clause.texts[0].text = text.replace(text, "N/A");
    } else if (clause.clauseName === "Date Of Joining") {
      const dateOfJoinToReplace = this.getText(text);
      if (dateOfJoin !== undefined)
        clause.texts[0].text = text.replace(dateOfJoinToReplace, dateOfJoin);
      else clause.texts[0].text = text.replace(dateOfJoinToReplace, "N/A");
    }
    console.log("ClasueText ==", clause.texts[0].text);
  }

  getText(text: string) {
    const splitArray = text.split(" ");
    for (let elementSplit of splitArray)
      if (elementSplit.includes("<<")) return elementSplit;
  }
}
```